# How to normalize paths pointing to members of an APFS Volume Group

Tags: macos, filesystems, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur

My code sometimes gets paths that point to the secondary volume of a volume group.

For instance, on a Catalina or Big Sur startup volume, where there's a System and a Data role member, I may have a path such as:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/bin
```

The regular ("normalized") path would be:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

How do I turn the first path into the second, using available macOS framework functions (Obj-C or Swift)?

Note that I don't want to simply hard-code a string replacement for this, because, at least on Big Sur, the same also happens with other mounted volumes that are in a group. For instance, I may have another bootable system with 10.15, whose volume is named "Catalina", and the two volumes then would appear as:

System: /Volumes/Catalina
Data: /Volumes/Catalina - Data

Now, if I get a path like `/Volumes/Catalina - Data/Users/Shared`, I want to normalize that into `/Volumes/Catalina/Users/Shared`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString`s `resolvingsymlinksinpath` method should do the trick!

Given `let path:String = "/System/Volumes/Data/Users/"`:

```
(lldb) po path
"/System/Volumes/Data/Users/"

(lldb) po (path as NSString).resolvingSymlinksInPath
"/Users"
```

Comment: Right. Actually, I was also wrong saying that NSURLCanonicalPathKey and URLByStandardizingPath would not work (I'll fix that). They do work, just not for the one path of "/System/Volumes/Data" (which I expected to become "/").

Answer (score 1):

Beside Patrick's answer, here are a few alternatives that should work as well:

```
// macOS 10.12 and later:
NSString *normalizedPath;
[url getResourceValue:&normalizedPath forKey:NSURLCanonicalPathKey error:nil];

// pre-10.12:
NSURL *normalizedURL = url.fileReferenceURL.filePathURL;
```

Also, the `fcntl` call `F_GETPATH_NOFIRMLINK` should work for this.

What does ***not*** work, though, is `[NSURL URLByStandardizingPath]`

Just be aware that the root of the firmlinked volume, e.g. `/System/Volumes/Data`, won't lead to `/` as one might have hoped. This one path requires special handling, i.e. one needs to detect that it's a volume (`NSURLIsVolumeKey`) and if so, determine its "master" member. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63886185/43615 for a way to accomplish that part.

For determining the normalized path in a shell (Terminal), see https://superuser.com/a/1490999/41872